# Auto Renewable Subscription issue with different sandbox users on Same device

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, auto-renewable

I am using Auto Renewable Monthly Subscription in my application and successfully implemented workflow. I am testing application in development mode i.e with sandbox environment. I have added two Sandbox users in iTunes connect > User and Roles Section.
Query -

1. When user monthly subscribe service using first sandbox account and successfully subscribed product. then user Sign Out first sandbox account from device Settings > iTunes and App Store Section and then again login with second sandbox test user.
   When user again open application then it show alert  - "you are currently Subscribed to this" with option to manage and Ok, Rather than asking to perform purchase with new second sandbox user. Please guide me what should be the correct behaviour.
2. How can I add cancel subscription within app and test with sandbox environment.
3. How does auto renewable - renew subscription and validate subscription work?

Kindly Suggest , I will be very thankful for guide lines.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,SandBox payment validity is 5 mins for monthly recurring payments. And for app inApp Payment details will save in appStoreReceiptURL this url, Apple will check based on Purchase_id(it will create in iTunes) and appStoreReceiptURL, If you want to use another Sandbox tester email You need to delete app and re install.then you will proceed to payment via SandBox.

```
2) There is no option to cancel Auto-renewable to sandbox payments.

3) Auto renewable will not work in Sandbox payments, it's for just testing purpose how inApp will work with out payment.
```

Comment: is it possible to get cancel date in sandbox environment?@Hari c only we could test in production environment?